# how to use access token one drive API using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oauth, oauth-2.0, access-token, onedrive

I want use the "one drive Api" with JavaScript: https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm
I get the "access_token" using the method "Code flow". I Get this:

```
{
    "token_type":"bearer",
    "expires_in":3600,
    "scope":"wl.signin wl.offline_access wl.basic wl.skydrive wl.skydrive_update onedrive.readwrite onedrive.appfolder",
    "access_token":"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","refresh_token":"MCWYiByRoP7HJxL3LSyi3Xw84RYva1l3!TIIxqoavyEmMawV3f5K0kX9YsqSjZIGjMKXhR9f4N7sY5njzwsNl3nzXSTQX25Ruc6ExH0lFVM2fwGAipLqP!IbtwSnSPgoigURfwvbgobqMjSFLu33iAM!qImWJjLZ3IOrNZ74E0vgFIGK0rgW8TCk!vu3eD5hlTQ!36RJCfCx1RqKS94Z0d1e99!xFAmR!L8VyxO4GNrHco0OzSkTb*WmJ*0QUE4hY5QSh8uXd*x*0r6kd2dsGbia7ypy5nCWJD7N*NY4t8CpFgvKEaL5E!l70XzJyfTfHDGzSyG7o*aNyRGYUwTnIXCGeCIJfj85ZmOj2IhIx9i84",
    "user_id":"a34b420ae6b20e72b2e15d5a25564c52"
}
```

I have the "access_token" but... i don't know how use it. What should I do with this?

Comment: Use JSON parse, grab the access token and store it somewhere (session storage for example) so you can send it up with future requests

Comment: you should put this token on your requests, so that your request is authorized for "one drive"

Comment: Yes, thank, but... how make the request with javascript? is it possible? I need send the access token with de the header "'Authorization: Bearer '+token" but i don't know do it.

Comment: You add a header to the request, if you use jquery it is easy. Just use the headers property on the ajax object: see here: http://zinoui.com/blog/ajax-basic-authentication

Comment: Oh thanks, that will serve me.

Thank all.

Comment: Just replace 'Basic' with 'Bearer' in the linked example and add your token on the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My app uses AngularJS to make the http calls as in:

```
    $scope.getUserAlbums = function (accessToken) {
    var userAlbumUrl = "https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root/children?access_token=" + accessToken;
    $http.get(userAlbumUrl).success(function (data) {
        $scope.albums = data.value;
    });
};
```

As you can see I am appending the access token to the end of the URL. I don't have a jQuery example but I expect it would be similar.